# Google Maps turn-by-turn navigation embedded

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Somehow possible embed Google Maps inside our iOS App and make the turn-by-turn navigation like lift app does? or its really a partnership feature?

Ref: https://blog.lyft.com/posts/announcing-lyft-navigation

Thank you in advanced

Comment: It seems to be partner feature. Looks at this presentation https://youtu.be/XVjyIA3f_Ic?t=1274

Comment: You should turn this comment into an answer, so it can be voted up.